# How to use only particular attributes of a class

Tags: typescript, object, attributes

My Project has a patient model, in which there are many attributes. I use few attributes in one page and few other attributes in another page. I have a common class and how do I use only few attributes in another method.

```
class Address {
constructor(
public addressLine1: String,
public addressLine2: String,
public city: String,
public state: String,
public zipcode: String
) { }
}

export class PatientModel {
constructor(
public firstName: String,
public lastName: String,
public dob: Date,
public addresses: Address,
public phone: String,
public validFlag: Boolean,
public medications: String,
public injuries: String,
public allergies: String,
public isSmoker: Boolean,
public isAlchoholic: Boolean,
public isAddict: Boolean
 ) { }

public static createBlank() {
let address = new Address('', '', '', '', '12345')
return new PatientModel('testfirst', 'testLast', new Date(1990, 4,4), 
address, '1234454343',  true,'','','',false,false,false);
}

public static medicalInfo(){
  // here i need only medications, allergies, injuries, smoker, alchoholic, 
     addict details..
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [optional or default parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters) in your constructor:

For example, to make `isAlchoholic` optional and `isAddict` have a default value:

```
export class PatientModel {
    constructor(
        public firstName: String,
        public lastName: String,
        public dob: Date,
        public addresses: Address,
        public phone: String,
        public validFlag: Boolean,
        public medications: String,
        public injuries: String,
        public allergies: String,
        public isSmoker: Boolean,
        public isAlchoholic?: Boolean,
        public isAddict: Boolean = false
    ) { }
}
```

Note that all optional/default parameters must follow all required parameters. You cannot have optional/default parameters between or before required parameters.